Was is der Unterschied zwischen "ziemlich" und "so ziemlich"?
Könntet ihr mir bitte sagen, was der Unterschied zwischen ziemlich und so ziemlich ist. Zum Beispiel:

Nikole weiß ziemlich alles über den Beruf.
Nikole weiß so ziemlich alles über den Beruf.

Ich habe eine Erklärung im Internet gesucht, aber ich konnte nichts finden.

So ziemlich wird im Gegensatz zu ziemlich eher mit alle oder jede verwendet und bedeutet dann ungefähr so viel wie fast:

Anna kennt hier ziemlich viele Leute.


Anna kennt hier so ziemlich jeden.


Ziemlich ist graduell, bezeichnet also einen verschiebbaren Wert auf einer Skala: "ziemlich groß" = "ein Wert, der schon weiter im großen Bereich ist als andere Werte".
So ziemlich ist punktuell, es sagt, dass man eine Sache schon so nennen kann: "Das ist so ziemlich alles" (hierbei ist "alles" nicht graduierbar). Meinem Empfinden nach klingt der Satz "Das ist so ziemlich groß" falsch, es müsste jedenfalls "groß" in irgendeinem endgültigen, bereits definierten Sinn gemeint sein.
Außerdem gehört in der Tat der Ausdruck so ziemlich einer umgangssprachlichen, saloppen Redeweise an.

Dieses so ist in diesem Kontext ein Modalpartikel, das den Satz noch lässiger einfärbt als er durch die Wortwahl ziemlich anstatt fast ohnehin schon ist.
